# Recreate network while using --force-recreate option of docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
services:
    container1:
        ...
    container2:
        ...
    ...
    containerx:
        ...
networks:
    default:
        name: default_network
        driver: bridge
        ipam:
            driver: default
            config:
                - subnet: "${DEFAULT_NETWORK}"
```

So, I have several containers in my `default_network`.
Now, I want to change the subnet of my network. Using `docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d --remove-orphans --force-recreate` recreate all my docker but leaves the network unchanged. Network isn't recreated.

Sure, I could stop all my containers and manually delete the network before executing this command, but it seems a little excessive to me...

Is there another way to do that properly?

Thanks!

Comment: Try not deleting your containers but rather 1) saving all connected containers to a file, 2) disconnecting all affected containers (`docker network disconnect <network> <container>`) 3) recreating the network and finally 4) reconnect all containers from the file (`docker network connect <network> <container>`)